# AlamoFire: How can get responseJSON values

Tags: swift, alamofire

Currently I'm using the new Swift Library Called AlamoFire and I want to get the JSON Response on a NSDictionary or make use of it on the app.

```
// Pasar Parametros al API
    let parameters = ["username": usuario.text,
        "password": contrasena.text,
        "type": "login_clients"]

    // Iniciar el POST request y esperar los datos y parsearlos
    Alamofire.request(.POST, "http://mycoolapi.com", parameters: parameters).responseJSON {

        (request, response, JSON, error) in

        // Imprimir JSON (response)
        var respuesta = JSON
        let transaccion = respuesta["transaction"]
        NSLog("Response: %@", transaccion)



        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("mostrar_menu", sender: self)


    }
```

The following is not working, Any idea what Im doing wrong?

Comment: What `error` did you get?

Comment: Use of unresolved identifier 'JSONValue' and also get 'AnyObject?' does not have a member named 'subscript'

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer is the following:

```
var info = JSON as NSDictionary
var transaction = info["transaction"] as String
var message = info["message"] as String
```

Need to set the JSON response as a NSDictionary and after this ise set you can use it as long you set the variable as a String Value.